# How to add javascript to html using beautiful soup?

Tags: javascript, python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm using beautiful soup to edit an html file. I've been able to add a  tag, but I'm having trouble adding my javascript code inside the script element.

I have the following code:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(differencehtml, 'html.parser')

# create a new tag
tag = soup.new_tag("script")
tag.append = jscodestring  # this is not adding the javascript to the html file
# tag.string = jscodestring # also tried this unsuccesfully

head = soup.find('head')

#insert new tag after head tag
head.insert_after(tag)
```

When I inspect the resulting html, it looks like this:

```
...
</head>
<script>
   </script>
...
```

Why does append not work? How do I get code inside the script tag?

Comment: See one of the answers in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32607284/how-to-insert-javascript-into-script-element) SO question.

Answer (score 1):

Append() is used to modify the tags's contents. Look at the documentation here, https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigablestring-and-new-tag .

This line of your code :

```
tag.append = jscodestring  # this is not adding the javascript to the html file
```

would need to look like this

```
tag.append(jscodestring)  # this is not adding the javascript to the html file
```

Even so, doing this would just place a string value of whatever jscodestring equals inside your tag's contents.

What you are looking to do is add a new attribute to your script tag.

This could be done somewhat like this. I can't see the contents of differencehtml so I cannot be sure.

```
soup.find('script')['selected'] = '<path to your javascript file>'
```

Check this post for another example, [BeautifulSoup - adding attribute to tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17497819/beautifulsoup-adding-attribute-to-tag) .

(EDIT) To get the code to look like this

```
<script> Hello World!</script>
```

you would just need to do `tag.append("Hello World!")` or place a variable that is a string inside append()

Comment: Thanks for your help! But isn't modifying the contents the same as adding a new attribute? I did the following: `soup.find('script')['selected'] = 'C:\\Users\\myname\\Documents\\my_file\\buttons.js` and the resulting html looked like this: `<script selected="C:\Users\myname\Documents\my_file\buttons.js">
 </script>`

Comment: I would like the code to look like this: `<script> 'Hello World!' </script>` and not `<script selected = 'Hello World!'> </script>`

Comment: @mir Sorry for misinterpreting. I edited the answer.